# Acces Terraform user-data variables through a Powershells script running on an EC2

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I'm working on automating some software installation on Windows AWS EC2. My infrastructure as a dev environment and a prod environment. So to handle that i'm trying to pass through user data some variables :

```
data "template_file" "template_name" {

  template = file("user-data/user-data-software.ps1")

  vars = {
    aws_region = var.region
    bucket_key = module.s3_access_key.bucket_id
    bucket_sim_files = module.s3_sim_files.bucket_id
  }
}
```

My issue is that I'm not able to access these variables, I couldn't get then through 'args' or with param.

Do you guys ever encounter this?

Comment: Usually you would drop using the `template_file` data source and start working with `templatefile` built-in function. Can you add the part with the script to the question as well?

Comment: Also, are you sure the modules have those outputs defined?

Comment: Yes I'm used to just call these variables with `$bucket_key` on template file running on linux Ec2, but most of what I've been through online to handle that on Windows Ec2 does not work. Yes the modules works fine on others templates, only having the issue with Windows on Powershell.

Comment: Ok, can you add the `user-data-software.ps1` to the question?